# How to fix eclipse spinning CPU while debugging on tomcat server

Tags: eclipse, cpu

I know stackoverflow is meant for programming problems, but this is exactly the kind of thing you search for on google and other people ask the same question with no answer, which is exactly the kind of thing I read stackoverflow was for.

I run ganymede I'm debugging a servlet in tomcat on windows. When I do a line by line trace, all of a sudden the CPU spikes. windows process status says it's eclipse.
The only other evidence of weirdness is that the heapsize report in the corner (next to the garbage collection button if you have that turned on) changes every second, up and down up and down. I gave it 256 megs and it's bouncing between 155, 169, 159, 164.... it just keeps changing up and down. But nothing's going on in my progress view pane. I tried giving it 512 megs no help (2 gig in the machine)

Any idea how to get eclipse to tell me what it's doing with all my cpu?
It makes the debugger unresponsive and nothing works. I get timeout errors on my step command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could launch your eclipse with a [jconsole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100161#101164) attached to it, provided you put in your [eclipse.ini settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357) the

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
```

option.

You will then be able to follow/record any thread/memory/objects usage during your session, collecting more clues as to what is going on.