# Eclipse not releasing console (log) memory after clearing

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse footprint is steadily increasing from 500MB to >1GB without me doing anything in particular - just running some log heavy programs. Doing a manual GC, closing and reopening projects does not help at all, once it's over 1GB it stays there.

I've run jvisualvm and found out from the heapdump that **hundreds of megabytes are char[] representing log output**.

I make it a habbit to close all the consoles of stopped processes, so it's not that.
Console buffer is set to 1MB (characters). I've closed the console view and reopened it again.

I can paste my particular eclipse.ini but I've tried different GC and memory settings, different JVMs, different Eclipse versions - behavior is still the same.

To me it seems that the logs are getting stuck with a reference somewhere and never get released. Is anyone else having this problem? **Is there a setting somewhere to release memory from old console views?**

Comment: Do you have a lot of source files open in the editor at the same time? In my experience closing all unused files releases a lot of memory.

Comment: Eclipse Juno and Helios. I only keep a few files open at a time, it makes no difference. It's just memory that never comes back no matter what I do and close, only a restart of Eclipse restores it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: heap size is not shrinking, only growing.

Long answer:
In the end it seemed like a combination of factors. I'm not completely sure what the JVM default options should be, but my XP machine has the Windows performance optimisation set to 'Server'/'Background applications'. I believe this also causes the JVM to default to the '-server' option instead of the '-client'.
The -server option does not allow the heap to shrink.

As far as I've found out, parallelGC does not allow the heap to shrink.

The default values for XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio (70) and XX:MinHeapFreeRatio (30) are pretty lazy in giving up free memory. Setting them to 20/10 will result in a heap size closer to actual usage.

Why is all of this important? Well, if you are developing a desktop application in Java your client might get upset with the ever-increasing memory usage and blame your bad programming. Kind of like what happens with Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

While I thought about something smart to write here I found this: [How to reduce Eclipse's memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490803/how-to-reduce-eclipses-memory-usage) Where the suggestion to disable spellchecking actually **made a lot of difference**.

So.. here is my own contribution: This might sound strange, but I've also noticed myself having a lot of unused breakpoints makes Eclipse sluggish. Regularly clearing all break points is a sound habit.

This is just a tip related to this, there's an option to show memory and to force an GC from within Eclipse. Under

*Preferences>General>Show Heap Status*

Comment: Thank, I used that option and forced GC from Eclipse and jvisualvm with no effect.