# How to stop Eclipse from crashing so frequently?

Tags: eclipse

What is the solution for Eclipse not to crash so frequently?

It is really difficult to close the Eclipse and import the project back to workspace again.

Please give me a solution as to how to avoid Eclipse crashing.

Comment: You're going to have to give us more details - what are you trying to do when it crashes? Are there any error messages?

Comment: Hi. When it stops responding i go to windows task manager and i and the process javaw.exe

Comment: - what are you trying to do when it crashes? Are there any error messages?

Comment: No,I don't get any error messages. It crashes when I am using eclipse,like 3 hours once it stops responding

Comment: it seems to be problem with jdk.previously i download jdk 6 from partner sites then it solved.try this.

Comment: i have jdk7 installed. should i go to jdk6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it crashed afte 3+ hours of usage, it may be a memory issue.

[How to reduce Eclipse's memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490803/how-to-reduce-eclipses-memory-usage)

Also, make sure you have the correct version installed for your machine from [a legitiment sourcce](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).