# Eclipse IDE High Memory Footprint

Tags: eclipse, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, memory-footprint

Why my IDE eclipse is consuming too much memory?
Even though I followed some optimizations posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318688/will-openjdk-jvm-ever-give-heap-memory-back-to-linux)

The big problem is the JVM don't give back memory to O.S, even that i use G1 GC.

The Java process is consuming about 2GB memory, but the committed memory of JVM is much smaller. 
This kind of behavior is only perceived after a long period running the IDE. Memory consumption is always increasing while using Eclipse, why does this happen?

[image: High memory footprint]

Comment: Which JDK version?  The memory model is different for JDK 8 and newer.  You might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458195/does-gc-release-back-memory-to-os

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does GC release back memory to OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458195/does-gc-release-back-memory-to-os)

Comment: Using OpenJDK version 1.8.0_131

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reduce Eclipse's memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490803/how-to-reduce-eclipses-memory-usage)